Asymptotic analysis of the finite product
I have the following product
$$\prod _{n=1}^{\frac{L}{2}} \frac{e^{-\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{L+1}\right)}{T}}+1}{e^{-\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{L}\right)}{T}}+1}$$
I am interested in understanding the $L\to \infty$ limit first and then the product's value as a function of parameter $T$. I can see that the double limit $L\to \infty$ and then $T\to \infty$ the product is 1. But I can only numerically see that in the limit $L\to \infty $ and then $T\to 0$ gives me $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ but if the limit is exchanged i.e. $T\to 0$ first and then $L\to \infty$ one gets $\frac{1}{2}$.
Is there a way to analyze this product in the limit $L\to \infty$ to get the full function of T or at least the correct asymptotic values at $T\to 0$ and to show that the order of the limit matters?

For $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ (in your case $\lambda=-2/T$) we have
$$
L(\lambda):=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^N\frac{1+\exp\left(\lambda\cos\frac{n\pi}{2N+1}\right)}{1+\exp\left(\lambda\cos\frac{n\pi}{2N}\right)}=\exp\left(\frac\lambda\pi\int_0^1\frac{\arccos x}{1+e^{-\lambda x}}\,dx\right).
$$

Indeed, the expression under the product sign equals
$$
F(\lambda,n,N):=1+\frac{\exp\big(\lambda\Delta(n,N)\big)-1}{1+\exp\left(-\lambda\cos\frac{n\pi}{2N}\right)},
$$
where, as $N\to\infty$, uniformly for $1\leqslant n\leqslant N$,
\begin{align}
\Delta(n,N)&:=\cos\frac{n\pi}{2N+1}-\cos\frac{n\pi}{2N}
\\&=2\sin\frac{(4N+1)n\pi}{4N(2N+1)}\sin\frac{n\pi}{4N(2N+1)}
\\&=2\sin\left[\frac{n\pi}{2N}+O\left(\frac1N\right)\right]\sin\left[\frac{n\pi}{8N^2}+O\left(\frac1{N^2}\right)\right]
\\&=2\left[\sin\frac{n\pi}{2N}+O\left(\frac1N\right)\right]\left[\frac{n\pi}{8N^2}+O\left(\frac1{N^2}\right)\right]
\\&=\frac{n\pi}{4N^2}\sin\frac{n\pi}{2N}+O\left(\frac1{N^2}\right).
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\log F(\lambda,n,N)=\frac{\frac{\lambda n\pi}{4N^2}\sin\frac{n\pi}{2N}}{1+\exp\left(-\lambda\cos\frac{n\pi}{2N}\right)}+O\left(\frac1{N^2}\right)
$$
and, after summing over $1\leqslant n\leqslant N$ and taking $N\to\infty$, we obtain
$$
\log L(\lambda)=\frac{\lambda\pi}4\int_0^1\frac{t\sin\frac{\pi t}2\,dt}{1+\exp\left(-\lambda\cos\frac{\pi t}2\right)},
$$
which gets the announced form after $\cos\frac{\pi t}2=x$.

The limit $T\to 0^+$ corresponds to $\lambda\to-\infty$. Taking $\lambda\to\infty$ in
$$
\log L(-\lambda)=-\frac1\pi\int_0^\lambda\frac{\arccos(t/\lambda)}{1+e^t}\,dt
$$
using DCT, we see that $\lim\limits_{\lambda\to-\infty}\log L(\lambda)=-\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+e^t}=-\frac12\log2$, as expected.

Another integral representation: $$\log L(\lambda)=\frac1\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\frac{1+e^{\lambda\cos t}}2,dt.$$
